# Separate panels for separate workspaces in tint2

Tags: 11.10, virtualdesktop

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 x64. I have tint2 installed in an attempt to get a GNOME2-like bottom-panel.

Suppose I have windows A, B, and C open on Desktop 1, and windows D and E on Desktop 2. Right now, panel buttons for all 5 windows are on the tint2 panels when I am on *any* desktop.

Is there a way to get tint2 to act like GNOME2 in this regard? (I.e., bottom panel should only show windows A,B,C on Desktop 1; D,E on Desktop2; no windows on Desktop 3 or Desktop 4).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, tint2 does not support this. See: http://code.google.com/p/tint2/issues/detail?id=94 . You can, however, install a modified version of gnome 2 supporting this feature called GNOME-shell.

Comment: Your;e welcome. You could try something like docky or cario-dock if you are okay with docks that will do that.

Comment: Anyone know it there's an implementation in sight? It feels like it's a bigger priority than a preferences GUI for instance. Amazing program though, I couldn't live without it and I wouldn't dream of going back to windows since I discovered this.

Comment: I'm not sure, you'd have to ask a tint2 developer. Cario-dock is amazing though, and provides some really awesome eye candy.

Answer (score 1):

That's innacurate. You can have tint2 show only buttons for the windows on the current desktop.

At your tintrc file (usually ~/.config/tint2/tintrc), edit this option accordingly, adding if there's none:

```
taskbar_mode = single_desktop
```

From tint2 0.7's manual:

> 3.2 Taskbar, multi-desktop, multi-monitor • taskbar_mode = single_desktop, multi_desktop or single_monitor
>
> taskbar_mode = single_desktop : tint show one taskbar with task of
>   current desktop
>
> taskbar_mode = multi_desktop : tint show one taskbar per virtual
>   desktop you can drag-and-drop task between desktop and clic on an
>   empty taskbar to switch desktop
>
> taskbar_mode = single_monitor : tint show one taskbar with task of
>   current monitor

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the option "taskbar_mode = single_monitor" in tintrc (Ubuntu 16.04)  and it works as described by "the dsc" with each display/desktop showing local items only which is the behaviour desired by the original poster.